# I am not getting the desired output. I want to extract particular set of files from a folder but the output is just a index provided

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, glob

```
# Folder path
folders = glob.glob("F:/TXTXT*")

# Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns={'Country','Speech','Session','Year'})

# Read speeches by India
i = 0 

for files in folders:
    speech = glob.glob(files+'\IND*.txt')

    with open(speech[0],encoding='utf8') as f:
        # Speech
        df.loc[i,'Speech'] = f.read()
        # Year 
        df.loc[i,'Year'] = speech.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]
        # Session
        df.loc[i,'Session'] = speech.split('_')[-2]
        # Country
        df.loc[i,'Country'] = speech.split('_')[0].split("\\")[-1]
       
        # Increment counter
        i += 1 
        
df.head()
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem? What do you get? What result do you expect? We can't read in your mind - you have to all describe in question (not in comment). And you should show what you have in file(s)

Comment: I don't understand what you do with `speech` - it is list of files and you use first name to read data `speech[0]` - but later you use this list liek string  `speech.split("_")` but `speech` still is list with filenames. Maybe you should use `print()` to see what you have variables.